# The probability of the intersection of the compliments of three events.

Tags: probability

> Knowing that $P(A)=0.1 \, , P(B)=0.3 \, , P(C)=0.3 $ find $P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c)$

I believe the solution is:

$$P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c) = 3 - 2 - 0.3 -0.3 -0.1 = 0.3 $$

My logic:

For $A^c$, we include B,C and the entire sample space.
For $B^c$ we include A,C and the entire sample space.
For $C^c$ we include A,B and the entire sample space.

In other words the events A,B,C are included 2 times, se we need to subtract P(A),P(B) and P(C) once and subtract the sample space twice.

Is my logic flawed? and is there a general formula for such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(A^{c}\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c})=P((A\cup B\cup C)^{c})=1-P(A\cup B\cup C)=1-(P(A)+P(B\cup C)-P(A\cap(B\cup C)))=1-P(A)-P(B\cup C)+P((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C))=1-P(A)-P(B)-P(C)+P(B\cap C)+ P(A\cap C)+P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap B\cap C)= 1- 0.1-0.3-0.3 + 0 + 0 + 0 - 0 = 0.3$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that A,B,C are mutually exclusive, so it does work out and give us 0.3 :)

Comment: @CivilSigma That was kind of important.  That means all the intersections to have a probability of zero.

Comment: But the way my thought process is correct? We've only just begun talking about probabilities.